# About sorting data in R

Tags: r

I am using the `table()` function to compare two columns like

```
table(bankMini$age, bankMini$job)
```

`bankMini$age` is numeric `bankMini$job` is categorical (factor)`

When I use it, it gives the result like this

[image]

On the far left side, there is age data.

I am trying to order the values in every column (ascending from top to bottom or vice-versa)
For example,

[image]

Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: You can use `apply(tbl, 2, sort, decreasing = TRUE)` if `tbl  <- table(bankMini$age, bankMini$job)`, but I am confused why you are breaking the order if the sort is to be performed on each column separately

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am examining at the boxplot() function with it (with ~) and observing the min and max lvls of the columns as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you describe:

```
# Make some toy data
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
age <- rnbinom(n = n, size = 25, prob = 0.5)
job <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = n, replace = TRUE)


tab <- table(age, job)
head(tab)
#    job
#age  A B C D E
#  7  0 0 0 0 1
#  8  0 0 0 0 1
#  9  0 0 0 2 1
#  10 1 0 1 1 0
#  11 2 1 1 0 1
#  12 2 4 0 3 1    

# Sort each column indiviually, and get corresponding groups in the rows
out <- sapply(1:ncol(tab), 
              function(i) rownames(tab)[order(tab[, i], decreasing = TRUE)])
colnames(out) <- colnames(tab)
head(out)
#     A    B    C    D    E   
#[1,] "24" "28" "19" "23" "23"
#[2,] "20" "18" "22" "27" "24"
#[3,] "27" "21" "18" "17" "22"
#[4,] "18" "17" "31" "25" "26"
#[5,] "25" "26" "27" "29" "21"
#[6,] "29" "19" "16" "18" "25"

# If you need it to be numeric
class(out) <- "numeric"
head(out)
#      A  B  C  D  E
#[1,] 24 28 19 23 23
#[2,] 20 18 22 27 24
#[3,] 27 21 18 17 22
#[4,] 18 17 31 25 26
#[5,] 25 26 27 29 21
#[6,] 29 19 16 18 25
```

Now, you should be aware that you loose the connection between the rows you have in the original table. The first row is simply the most frequent group within that column, the second row is the second most frequent group within a given column, and so on.